# Anki: Dealing with enumerations

Tags: anki

I am learning Anki in order to learn languages. I am reading the article https://www.supermemo.com/en/archives1990-2015/articles/20rules that the Anki Manual says to read, and I am at point #10 where enumerations and overlapping cloze deletions are discussed. Dr. Wozniak says if you have 1 card that asks for the order of the alphabet vs many cards with overlapping cloze deletions, the advantage of the latter is "the student does not have to stop repetitions to recite the whole sequence." In other words, it takes more time to do every card if you do the 1 card option. Later, Dr. Wozniak says that you should still try to recite the whole alphabet after each cloze card. Doesn't this defeat the time advantage of the cloze method?